# How can i make a div take all empty space in a col with a vh-100 using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, bootstrap-5

In the `<div class="bg-primary"></div>`  i want it to take what's remaining of the empty space but not going out of the vh-100 tried every possible solution but i couldn't find how I can fix it

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  width: 336px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- font aweseome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.png" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<section style="background-color: #f9f9f9">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <!-- ! -->
      <div
        class="navbar col-2 d-flex vh-100 flex-column"
        style="background-color: #ffff"
      >
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand mt-3 mb-4">
            <img src="/img/no-bg.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
          </a>

          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a
              class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary-emphasis"
              aria-current="page"
              href="#"
            >
              <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Home</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary-emphasis" href="#"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-wallet"></i> Balance</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary-emphasis" href="#"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-arrow-left"></i> Transaction</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary" href="#"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i> Settings</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary" href="#"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i> About Us</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Navbar -->
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col-10 vh-100">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end py-2 align-items-center">
          <img
            src="/img/default.png"
            alt="profile pic"
            class="rounded-5"
            style="height: 35px; width: 35px"
          />
          <h6 class="px-2" style="margin: 0">Fahchouch Mohammed</h6>
        </div>
        <h2 class="my-3">Dashboard</h2>

        <!-- Cards -->
        <div class="row g-1">
          <!-- First card -->
          <div class="col-3 card text-bg-primary p-3 rounded-4 mx-4">
            <div class="card-subtitle" style="font-size: x-small">
              My Balance
            </div>
            <div class="card-title px-3"><h2>$0</h2></div>
            <div class="row mx-3" style="font-size: 0.7rem">
              <div class="col-6">
                <div style="color: #b9b9ef">Card Holder</div>
                <div>Fahchouch Mohammed</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <div style="color: #b9b9ef">Valid Thru</div>
                <div>00/00</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Second Card -->
          <div
            class="col card rounded-4 mx-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
          >
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-4">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-coins" style="font-size: 2rem"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                Income
                <h2>$0</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Third card -->
          <div
            class="col card rounded-4 mx-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
          >
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-4">
                <i
                  class="fa-solid fa-money-bill-transfer"
                  style="font-size: 2rem"
                ></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                Expense
                <h2>$0</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Cards -->
        <div class="bg-primary"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `vh-100` element a vertical flex layout and `flex-grow` the `bg-primary` element to fill the remaining space:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  width: 336px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- font aweseome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.png" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<section style="background-color: #f9f9f9">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <!-- ! -->
      <div
        class="navbar col-2 d-flex vh-100 flex-column"
        style="background-color: #ffff"
      >
        <div class="container">
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand mt-3 mb-4">
            <img src="/img/no-bg.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
          </a>

          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a
              class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary-emphasis"
              aria-current="page"
              href="#"
            >
              <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Home</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary-emphasis" href="#"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-wallet"></i> Balance</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary-emphasis" href="#"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-arrow-left"></i> Transaction</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary" href="#"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i> Settings</a
            >
            <a class="nav-link my-2 text-secondary" href="#"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i> About Us</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Navbar -->
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col-10 vh-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-stretch">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end py-2 align-items-center">
          <img
            src="/img/default.png"
            alt="profile pic"
            class="rounded-5"
            style="height: 35px; width: 35px"
          />
          <h6 class="px-2" style="margin: 0">Fahchouch Mohammed</h6>
        </div>
        <h2 class="my-3">Dashboard</h2>

        <!-- Cards -->
        <div class="row g-1">
          <!-- First card -->
          <div class="col-3 card text-bg-primary p-3 rounded-4 mx-4">
            <div class="card-subtitle" style="font-size: x-small">
              My Balance
            </div>
            <div class="card-title px-3"><h2>$0</h2></div>
            <div class="row mx-3" style="font-size: 0.7rem">
              <div class="col-6">
                <div style="color: #b9b9ef">Card Holder</div>
                <div>Fahchouch Mohammed</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <div style="color: #b9b9ef">Valid Thru</div>
                <div>00/00</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Second Card -->
          <div
            class="col card rounded-4 mx-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
          >
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-4">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-coins" style="font-size: 2rem"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                Income
                <h2>$0</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Third card -->
          <div
            class="col card rounded-4 mx-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
          >
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-4">
                <i
                  class="fa-solid fa-money-bill-transfer"
                  style="font-size: 2rem"
                ></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                Expense
                <h2>$0</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Cards -->
        <div class="bg-primary flex-grow-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```